# OneNote 2016 cannot get my notebooks after Windows update

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office, onedrive, microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2016

I am using Windows 7 and MS Office Professional Plus 2016. Everything works fine until Windows pushed me to update which includes many MS Office updates yesterday. I did and then OneNote stopped working for me. I tried to reinstall the Office. But the result is the same. OneNote (And OneNote for Windows 10) works fine on my other Windows 10 machines.

I have OneDrive (the personal one, not the one for Business) installed.

Cannot find a solution online. Hope experts here can help me figure it out.

[image]

Comment: Look in your One Drive folder and see if you can copy the One Note file to a different location and open it that way.

Comment: There are a few Internet Shortcut files inside my OneDrive\Documents folder. They cannot be opened (nothing happened) by OneNote.

Comment: Updates to One Note have exceeded the abilities of Windows 7?

Comment: I found some ".one" and ".onetoc2" files in other local user folders. Some of them can be opened with read-only mode and some of them just make OneNote "No Responding". I tried to install the latest OneNote (click and run version) but it conflicts with my Office Professional (installer version?).

Comment: You may need to try recovering with a newer machine.

Comment: Sign out and re-sign in your accounts and recreate connections.

Comment: After signing out, I cannot sign in again, telling me "Sorry, we are having some temporary server issues."